# Pass class to children component host

Tags: css, angular

I'm used to React approach where I could basically inject anything anywhere.

I have a dumb `Button` or `app-button` component in Angular. It's inline-block (`:host` class), so its width depends on the content. In this case, I can't override its params like `display: block` or set width. I can do it manually by adding new `@Input` per param (`[display]`, `[width]`) but it's not really nice.

The behavior I want to have is an input/directive on this component to provide an explicitly inject class to the inside of the child component.

In React I would just add prop with the class name and assign it or pass some inline styles, depending on what style system I'm using.

Is there any way/lib/util to handle this problem?

Comment: Could you take a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52540888/3345644) please and consider making it as an accepted one since it's more code maintenance-friendly and doesn't suggest working around the explicitly set behavior? Also according to  upvotes, it's actually more helpful to current readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the Angular's [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation) you cannot do it the way React does.

Your best bet is to style the button `:host` element directly. This way you can override it with classes defined in the parent component.

**app-button.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  template: `
    I am red by default
  `,
  styles: [`
  :host {
    background-color: red;
  }
  `]
})
export class ButtonComponent {}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <app-button class="button"></app-button>
  `,
  styles: [
    `.button { 
       background-color: blue; 
     }
    `
  ]
})
export class AppComponent  {}
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8vc6ec)

Answer (score 5):

You should not write CSS rules for a child component elements in a parent component, since an Angular component is a self-contained entity which should explicitly declare what is available for the outside world. If child layout changes in the future, your styles for that child component elements scattered across other components' SCSS files could easily break, thus making your styling very fragile. That's what `ViewEncapsulation` is for in the case of CSS. Otherwise, it would be the same if you could assign values to private fields of some class from any other class in Object Oriented Programming.

Therefore, what you should do is to define a set of classes you could apply to the child host element and implement how the child responds to them.

Technically, it could be done as follows:

```
// child.component.html:
<span class="label-1"></span>

// child.component.scss:
:host.child-color-black {
    .label-1 {
        color: black;
    }
}

:host.child-color-blue {
    .label-1 {
        color: blue ;
    }
}

// parent.component.html:
<child class="child-color-black"></child>
<child class="child-color-blue"></child>
```

In other words, you use `:host` pseudo-selector provided by Angular + set of CSS classes to define possible child styles in child component itself. You then have the ability to trigger those styles from outside by applying pre-defined classes to the `<child>` host element.

Answer (score 3):

Today there are a couple of other possibilities:

:host-context(.some-class-name)
This lets you react on some outer class

::ng-deep css-expression{ xx }
This way you can define a class in the parent that will be available in it's children.

---

**Example:**

parent.component.html

```
<app-button class="theme-blue"> my button </app-button>
```

button.component.css

```
:host-context(.theme-blue) button {
   background-color: blue;
}
```

One may as well check out this very well guide: 
https://alligator.io/angular/styles-between-components-angular/

Comment: `ng-deep` is deprecated: angular.io/guide/component-styles

Comment: ```+1``` for the use of `host-context`